# How to use __mul__ in a class named Fraction

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make multiplication work with my class `Fraction`?

```
class Fraction(object):

    def __init__(self, num, den):
        self.num = num
        self.den = den

    def resolve(self):
        #a = 2
        #b = 6
        #c = 2
        #d = 5
        self.num = self.num / other.num
        self.den = self.den / other.den
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return "%d/%d" %(self.num, self.den)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        den = self.den * other.num
        num = self.num * other.den
        return (Fraction(self.num * other.num, self.den * other.den))

print('Multiplication:', Fraction.__mul__(2, 6))
```

This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 43, in <module>
    print('Multiplication:', Fraction.__mul__(2, 6))
  File "app.py", line 27, in __mul__
    den = self.den * other.num
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'den'
```

Comment: ```Fraction.__mul__(2, 6)``` is not an instance of the object. You have to initialize the Fraction object. ```Fraction(2,6).__mul__(Fraction(1,3))```, but you don't even need to do that because you __mul__ maps to the asterisk. ```Fraction(2,6) * Fraction(1,3)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
f1 = Fraction(1, 2)
f2 = Fraction(2, 3)

print(f1 * f2)
```

Here I'm

- Creating an object `f1` of class `Fraction` this is `1/2`
- Similarly `f2` which is `2/3`
- Now `f1 * f2` automatically calls the dunder method `__mul__` of `f1` with `f2` as the `other` argument
- So you should see the expected `Fraction` object getting printed

PS: The reason why you're getting the `AttributeError` is because, `__mul__` expects `Fraction` objects to be passed - while you are passing `int`s

Comment: `print(f1 * f2)`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh fixed

Comment: Thanks, I can see my mistake now, is much easier doing this way :)